# Explain COBOL-DB2 compilation in ubuntu linux in opencobol?

Tags: gnucobol

I wanted to run my cobol-db2 program in ubuntu linux using opencobol compiler, please explain me the process of running my program in linux using opencobol.

Answer (score 1):

Please excuse me if this is breaking any age limit rules on Stackoverflow;

See http://opencobol.add1tocobol.com/#how-does-the-opencobol-compiler-work

and maybe http://opencobol.add1tocobol.com/#does-opencobol-support-any-sql-databases

for a sample of linking to database libraries.

**Edit: As suggested by mbinette, instead of simple links**

In short, OpenCOBOL is a multi phase compiler.

- Preprocess the source text. **cobc -E** to generate post processed text to stdout and stop
- Translate to C. **cobc -C** to generate .c source code files and stop
- Translate to assembler using native C compiler. **cobc -S** to generate .s assembler source and stop
- Generate object. **cobc -c** will generate .o object files and stop
- Build. **cobc -x**, or **cobc -m**, or **cobc -b** for executable, module (.so or DLL), and finally build for creating dynamic shared objects out of multiple command line inputs.

OpenCOBOL excels at shared libraries and by using the C Application Binary Interface, can dynamically load most if not all .so (or DLL) symbols using the COBOL **CALL** verb.

```
CALL "DB2-CONNECT"
    USING
        BY REFERENCE "database name"
        BY CONTENT credentials
        BY VALUE control-bits
    RETURNING pointer-to-handle
    ON EXCEPTION
        DISPLAY "Can't find DB2-CONNECT, use -ldb2 with cobc" END-DISPLAY
END-CALL
```

*I made up the above call frame, as I don't have a DB2 library or the docs at hand*.

To compile a program to use DB2 services you'd use something like

```
cobc -x myprogram.cob -ldb2 -L/path/to/DB2lib
```

or, more likely in a larger application, something along the lines of

```
cobc -b myprogram.cob hisprogram.cob herprogram.cob
export COB_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/development/libraries
export COB_PRE_LOAD=db2-dev:other-dev-libs
cobcrun myprogram
```

For more details, see the FAQ, *hopefully forever stashed at the links above*.

Pointing out that **OpenCOBOL as of 1.1 does NOT support EXEC syntax**.  DB2 EXEC preprocessors may or may not generate COBOL suitable for OpenCOBOL. *I've been told the Oracle Pro*COBOL EXEC END-EXEC precompiler generates COBOL source code that compiles with OpenCOBOL for linking to Oracle SQL.*

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.